# Enclosing brace code navigation in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 for C# and Visual Basic. The command `Options > Keyboardboard > Edit.GotoBrace` is configured to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. Two example uses:

#### Example 1

```
if (something)
{ // Place cursor on this brace, hit Edit.GotoBrace...
    DoSomething();
} // ...and end up here! Nice.
```

#### Example 2

```
#region Constants // Place cursor on this #region, hit Edit.GotoBrace...
public readonly string CONSTANT001 = "a001";
//...
public readonly string CONSTANT100 = "a100";
#endregion // ...and end up here! Nice, again.
```

The equivalent `#Region / #End Region` navigation works in VB, but not `If Then / End If` and other similar constructs. Is there anything in Visual Basic that would work in the example below?

```
If (something) Then // Place cursor here. Is there a keyboard shortcut or command...
    DoSomething()
End If // ...to end up here?
```

Comment: `CTRL+SHIFT+UP/DOWN`?

Comment: @Jimi: Not in my Visual Studio. `Ctrl + Shift + Up` takes focus from the code to the "project" dropdown, and `Ctrl + Shift + Down` sets focus to the "zoom" dropdown at the bottom.

Comment: 1. Commands in VB and C# are not 1-to-1 for everything. 2. There is options key shortcuts settings you can check and set the way you want.. I remember in good old days  VS would ask you - do you want vb or c# developer settings.

Comment: Hard to say, I have a custom configuration that I migrate to new versions of VS. Those shortcuts are linked to `Edit.PreviousHighlightedReference` / `Edit.NextHighlightedReference` in the Text Editor. In the Visual Designer, to `Edit.SizeControlUp` and `Edit.SizeControlDown`